# A 3 digit stopwatch

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I decided to make a stopwatch as I decided it would be useful, and also as a challenge to learn more about how forms work. I'd just like some simple advice as to anything I can do better, thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stopwatch
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        int seconds = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int hours = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IncrementStopwatch();
            UpdateLabels();
        }

        private void IncrementStopwatch()
        {
            seconds++;
            if (seconds == 60)
            {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
                if (minutes == 60)
                {
                    minutes = 0;
                    hours++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdateLabels()
        {
            Seconds.Text = KeepStyle(seconds);
            Minutes.Text = KeepStyle(minutes);
            Hours.Text = KeepStyle(hours);
        }

        private string KeepStyle(int s)
        {
            if (s <= 9)
                return "0" + s.ToString();
            return s.ToString();
        }

        private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
            if (!timer.Enabled)
                StartStopButton.Text = "Start";
            else if (timer.Enabled)
                StartStopButton.Text = "Stop";
        }

        private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 0;
            hours = 0;
            UpdateLabels();
            timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled; // Reset timer so it ticks in 1 second.
            timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

- Use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch instead of keeping separate variables for hour, minute and seconds. It already has all the logic for Start/Stop/Reset, the logic of seconds overflowing to minutes. etc. Another benefit is that it is more accurate. However you will still need to have a timer to refresh the user interface.
- Use consistent naming for form controls; buttons could end with "Button" and Labels could end with "Label".
- Drag the Timer component from the toolbox to your form instead, this allow Windows.Forms to dispose it properly for you.
- Remove unused usings.

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace Stopwatch
  {
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
          private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

          public Form1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();

              // TODO: Move to winforms designer.
              timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
              timer.Enabled = true;
          }

          private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              var elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;

              SecondsLabel.Text = elapsed.Seconds.ToString("00");
              MinutesLabel.Text = elapsed.Minutes.ToString("00");
              HoursLabel.Text = elapsed.Hours.ToString("00");
          }

          private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              if (stopwatch.IsRunning)
              {
                  StartStopButton.Text = "Start";
                  stopwatch.Stop();
              }
              else
              {
                  StartStopButton.Text = "Stop";
                  stopwatch.Start();
              }
          }

          private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              var isRunning  = stopwatch.IsRunning;
              stopwatch.Reset();
              if (isRunning)
              {
                  stopwatch.Start();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
    private string KeepStyle(int s)
    {
        if (s <= 9)
            return "0" + s.ToString();
        return s.ToString();
    }
```

you can do:

```
s.ToString("00");
```

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

---

Instead of:

```
    private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
        if (!timer.Enabled)
            StartStopButton.Text = "Start";
        else if (timer.Enabled)
            StartStopButton.Text = "Stop";
    }
```

You can do:

```
    private void StartStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start = DateTime.Now; // See below
        timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
        StartStopButton.Text = timer.Enabled ? "Stop" : "Start";
    }
```

---

Consider to use a `DateTime` object instead of your `hours, minutes, seconds` fields:

```
private DateTime start;
```

You can then skip the `IncrementStopwatch()` method and in `UpdateLabels()` do something like this:

```
    private void UpdateLabels()
    {
        TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - start;
        Seconds.Text = duration.Seconds.ToString("00");
        Minutes.Text = duration.Minutes.ToString("00");
        Hours.Text = duration.Hours.ToString("00");
    }
```

---

Remember to dispose the `Timer` object, when disposing the `Form`

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
        components.Dispose();
      }
      if (disposing)
      {
        if (timer != null) timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

(`Dispose(bool disposing)` can be found in Form1.Designer.cs)